# $_GET[] returns zero in editing page in php

Tags: php, get, httpresponse

Im editing the database record by pressing Edit button from `auditplan.php` page and redirecting to edit page(`auditplanedit.php`) by sending selected record id as follow:

```
<td> 
    <a href="auditplanedit.php?cid=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><i class="ion ion-edit"></i></a>
    <a href="deleteauditplan.php?cid=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><i class="ion ion-close"></i></a>                
</td>
```

First im placing all data in to the controls using *SELECT* statement and after editing, for updating im saving the edited data to the database using *UPDATE* statement,here im using 'id' which i got from `auditplan.php` using `$_GET['id']` .
For SELECT statement these id returns correct selected value but during update it shows zero.

```
<?php
include("config.php"); 
include("header.php"); 
 try {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM auditplan WHERE id = :cid";
   $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindValue(":cid",intval($_GET['cid']));   
   $stmt->execute();
   $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}

?>    

<div class="col-md-10 main">       

    <h1 class="page-header">
         Audit Plan Edit          
    </h1>   

 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="auditplanedit.php" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="usr">Audit ID:</label>  
    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
      <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="auditid" name ="auditid"  value="<?php echo $results[0]["auditid"] ?>">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Year:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-3" id="year" name ="year" value="<?php echo $results[0]["year"] ?>">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="usr">Month:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="month" name ="month" value="<?php echo $results[0]["month"] ?>">
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="sel1">Status:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="status">
        <option>Planned</option>
        <option>Scheduled</option>
        <option>Completed</option>
        <option>Cancelled</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="comment">Comment:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment" name="comment" value="<?php echo $results[0]["comment"] ?>"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="form-group">        
      <div class=" col-sm-offset-3">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id ="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        <button type="submit" name="submit1" id ="clear" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
      </div>

 </div>     
</form>           
</div>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {               
            $audit=trim($_REQUEST['auditid']);
            $year=trim($_REQUEST['year']);
            $month=trim($_REQUEST['month']);        
            $status =$_REQUEST['status'];
            $comment=$_REQUEST['comment'];
            $cid = intval($_GET['cid']);  ////here it returns zero

            $sql = "UPDATE auditplan SET `auditid` = :audit, `year` = :year, `month` = :month, `status` = :status, `comment` = :comment" . "WHERE id = :cid ";


        try {           
              $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);            
              $stmt->bindValue(":audit", $audit);
              $stmt->bindValue(":year", $year);
              $stmt->bindValue(":month", $month);
              $stmt->bindValue(":status", $status);
              $stmt->bindValue(":comment", $comment); 
              $stmt->bindValue(":cid", $cid);                
              $stmt->execute();
              $result = $stmt->rowCount();    

            } 
            catch (Exception $ex)
            {
              $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
              $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = $ex->getMessage();
            }       
    }               
?>
```

Comment: Please use `$getId = $row["id"];` and <a href="auditplanedit.php?cid=<?php echo $getId; ?>">

Comment: you need to create a `hidden field` for it inside your form `<input  type="text"   name ="cid"  value="<?php echo $row["id"]?>">` and in second query use `$_POST['cid']` to get you `cid`
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your form is using the POST method `method="POST"` but you are trying to access `$_GET['cid']`

Secondly, you do not have an input field in the form called `cid` so even if you used `$_POST['cid']` you would not get anything.

So first of all you need to add a field called `cid` to your form, now I would use a `hidden` field like this, so the user will not see it.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="auditplanedit.php" method="POST">


<input type="hidden" name="cid" value="<?php echo $results[0]['id'] ?>">


<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="usr">Audit ID:</label>  
    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
      <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="auditid" name ="auditid"  value="<?php echo $results[0]['auditid'] ?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your update query use that new value like this

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {               
        $audit=trim($_REQUEST['auditid']);
        $year=trim($_REQUEST['year']);
        $month=trim($_REQUEST['month']);        
        $status =$_REQUEST['status'];
        $comment=$_REQUEST['comment'];
        //$cid = intval($_GET['cid']);  ////here it returns zero
        $cid = intval($_POST['cid']);  // changed line
```

Answer (score -1):

You use double quotes(*"*) within which is wrong. Please try below:

**Note**: Make sure your `$row["id"]` contain proper value.

**first code section**:

```
<?php
//Store id into variable...
$getId = $row["id"];
?>

<td> 
    <a href="auditplanedit.php?cid=<?php echo $getId; ?>"><i class="ion ion-edit"></i></a>
    <a href="deleteauditplan.php?cid=<?php echo $getId; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><i class="ion ion-close"></i></a>                
</td>
```

**second code section**:

```
<?php
include("config.php"); 
include("header.php"); 
 try {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM auditplan WHERE id = :cid";
   $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindValue(":cid",intval($_GET['cid']));   
   $stmt->execute();
   $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}

?>    

<div class="col-md-10 main">       

    <h1 class="page-header">
         Audit Plan Edit          
    </h1>   

 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="auditplanedit.php" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="usr">Audit ID:</label>  
    <div class="col-sm-5"> 
      <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="auditid" name ="auditid"  value="<?php echo $results[0]['auditid'] ?>">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Year:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-3" id="year" name ="year" value="<?php echo $results[0]['year'] ?>">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="usr">Month:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="month" name ="month" value="<?php echo $results[0]['month'] ?>">
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2 " for="sel1">Status:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="status">
        <option>Planned</option>
        <option>Scheduled</option>
        <option>Completed</option>
        <option>Cancelled</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="comment">Comment:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment" name="comment" value="<?php echo $results[0]['comment'] ?>"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="form-group">        
      <div class=" col-sm-offset-3">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id ="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        <button type="submit" name="submit1" id ="clear" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
      </div>

 </div>     
</form>           
</div>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {               
            $audit=trim($_REQUEST['auditid']);
            $year=trim($_REQUEST['year']);
            $month=trim($_REQUEST['month']);        
            $status =$_REQUEST['status'];
            $comment=$_REQUEST['comment'];
            $cid = intval($_GET['cid']);  ////here it returns zero

            $sql = "UPDATE auditplan SET `auditid` = :audit, `year` = :year, `month` = :month, `status` = :status, `comment` = :comment" . "WHERE id = :cid ";


        try {           
              $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);            
              $stmt->bindValue(":audit", $audit);
              $stmt->bindValue(":year", $year);
              $stmt->bindValue(":month", $month);
              $stmt->bindValue(":status", $status);
              $stmt->bindValue(":comment", $comment); 
              $stmt->bindValue(":cid", $cid);                
              $stmt->execute();
              $result = $stmt->rowCount();    

            } 
            catch (Exception $ex)
            {
              $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
              $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = $ex->getMessage();
            }       
    }               
?>
```

Comment: I tried the same mentioned by you. but still it returns zero. Did you change anything in second section of code. I think problem is in edit.php page.

Comment: Ok, let me check it again.

Comment: I just confirm $row['id'] having non zero value and my answer second section is edit.php(i.e. auditplanedit.php) right?

Comment: yes. i thought you found some error in my auditplanedit.php, thats why you are added the second section code. But i could not find any changes there.And also as my SELECT working fine in the same php page, why the second time when im getting $_GET['cid']  returns zero.

Comment: I made more then one replace task as I suggest in my answer first line. Check second section code again.

Comment: If you click on <a> what is the your URL in browser?